# How do i use static members in my application, which is in my library's dependency

Tags: dart, stagexl

I'm making a HTML5 game engine [DartRocket](https://github.com/StrykerKKD/dartrocket), which depends on [StageXL](https://github.com/bp74/StageXL). StageXL has some class, which is full of static members and I need some of them in my game.

My problem is that I can use these static members in my library(DartRocket), but I can't reach them from my game which uses my library.
Basically, because I can't see my library's dependency from my game. 
When I say game I mean one of my examples in my library.

My question is: How should I access these static members?

I have some solutions in mind:

1. Let the user import StageXL so he can access them
2. Copy-paste the whole class into my library
3. Use mirror API

I find the first solution stupid, because the user have to import StageXL and because my library already depends on it.

I use the second one, because I find it easy and I wanted to make changes to the class, but this is not ideal either, because i have to update it myself, if there is a change in the library's dependency.

I have not tried the third solution yet, because I don't really like to use mirrors, because it increases code complexity and the usage became based on the member's name(String).

Some "solutions" that didn't work:

1. Making an instance of the class (it was embarrassing and stupid to hope it will work :D)
2. Extending the class(doesn't work because static members are not inherited)

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a library in dart you can re-export other libraries.

So for example:

The StageXL Library:

```dart
library stagexl;

// parts
// definitions
// ...
```

And your library:

```
library dartrocket;

export 'stagexl.dart';
```

Afterwards you can use:

```
import 'dartrocket.dart';

SomeStageXLClass.method();
```

This way the user can use your lib and also use the methods and classes from the stagexl library. By using the `show` keyword you can also define which classes to export.

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have seen export in some libraries, but I never know what it actually does, but now i do.